# How to do this CSS animation? (timing-function)

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions, css-animations

I want an animation like this:

[image: like this]

(The lower blue line is an image of movement. lol)

I tried to make with cubic-bezier but it didn't work..

---

I don't know much about css animation, but cubic-bezier can add points other than the first and last?
In my opinion, I feel like I should increase points..

**Q**. What kind of curve should I use for css animation like this?

Comment: That's not possible with CSS animation, the cubic-bezier it's only for the easing of the animation, not for animate. I'll do it with SVGs playing with the stroke offset.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: @GiuMagnani Oh really? :( I should use SVG. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> That's not possible with CSS animation -Gui Magnani

If you manualy set the animations times and keyframes you can get close to your drawing.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px green;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px green;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
  }
  20% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100px green;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
  }
  30% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 90px green;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
  }
  90% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  95% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px green;
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```